# Validation rules from entity mapping metadata

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

Can someone, please, give me some enlightenment about how Symfony2 uses the ORM metadata to automatically build validation rules? I'm using Symfony2.1.

For example, if we have a `Foo` entity with a required `name` attribute, we have the following Doctrine metada (as annotation):

```
@ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
```

But then we have to repeat the `nullable` information with `Assert` if we want it to be validated in the server side:

```
@Assert\NotBlank()
```

In the other side, if we have a `number` attribute with an `integer` type, this is automatically used as a validation rule without the need of using any `@Assert` annotation.

```
@ORM\Column(name="number", type="integer", nullable=true)
//@Assert\Type(type="integer") is no needed
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you have two different layers:

- the persistence layer (Doctrine2, Propel, ...);
- the [Validation layer](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/validation.html).

The peristence layer adds validation rules to the database using metadata. In Doctrine2, you can use annotations, but with Propel you describe your database using XML. It's mainly used to define SQL statements (basically `nullable=false` is transformed in SQL `NOT NULL`).

The validation layer is used to validate your data at the application level. Doctrine2 metadata are used to construct your database while the Validation layer is used to validate data (from your users for example) before to insert them in the database.

You can add more constraints at the application level using the Validator component like business validation rules. And, you should not rely on the database to validate data.

As you have two different layers with two different concerns, you can't mix them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @WilliamDURAND. But the fact is that at some point both layers are being mixed. As I said, if an `integer` constraint is set by the ORM, this is also used by the validation layer. But, for example, the `nullable` constraint is not used.

Comment: Are you sure it's not part of the Form component? The Form component is able to guess types based on Doctrine metadata, and some types implement validation (HTML5 validation for example).

Comment: I think it has to be the validation component, at least it works the same way. I disable HTML5 validation and the server is displaying the error message about the field type and no validation constraint has been added. Maybe the Form and Valdation components have similar behavior at some point?? :S

Comment: If you get an "unexpected type" error, that's because a NumberType uses a transformer which validates data: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer.php#L73

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain it well. I don't get any HTTP error, it is just that in the form an error message is displayed to tell the user that another value was expected.

Comment: I understood but there is no relation between the validation layer and Doctrine metadata.